# How to use Angular directive in html attribute

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a translationDirective to translate a text in my template.

```
<span translate="{{label}}">{{label}}</span>
```

Is it possible to use the translated value also in a html attribute?

```
<span translate="{{label}}" someOtherAttribute="translatedLabel">{{label}}</span>
```

Comment: what is translatedLabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes are used to modify data . And directives are used to update DOM.Can you please post your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, a pipe did the job... i completely forgot that pipes